# Which shape should have input and output data for a LSTM NN?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, neural-network, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I have a problem with the way of creating my data for a NN with a LSTM layer. I have **many files** containing hundreds of lines. **Each file represents a song** and **each line represents a note with 4 values**. I want the NN read the notes with **a sequence of 10 notes** so that it can predict the next note from them. If it is needed, we can fix the number of notes at 5000 per song.

So I just want to know which **shape my input and output data** should have and how to define the first LSTM layer.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape=(5000, 4),return_sequences=True))
```

To sump up:

- One file has 5000 lines and 4 columns and represents 1 song.
- One line in a file represent one note with 4 values.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample of the input data?

Comment: The input data has thousands of lines so I cant provide it here.There are 4 columns and each value is a number between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input shape of the first LSTM layer should be `(None, 10, 4)`.
The output shape of the model would be `(None, 4)`. I use `None` for the batch size.

I coded a simple LSTM as an example:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.models import Sequential

batch_size = 32
window_length = 10
note_dim = 4
n_samples = 5000

# Input data. TODO: Slide window and modify it to use real data
x = np.ones(shape=(n_samples, window_length, note_dim))
y = np.ones(shape=(n_samples, note_dim))

# Define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(note_dim, input_shape=(window_length, note_dim))) # The batch dimension is implicit here

model.compile('sgd', 'mse')
model.fit(x=x, # Batch input shape is: (None, window_length, note_dim)
          y=y, # Batch output shape is: (None, note_dim)
          batch_size=batch_size)
```

In case you want a more complex model (i.e. 2 LSTM layers) you could define it this way:

```
# ...
# Define model
hidden_size = 50
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(hidden_size, input_shape=(window_length, note_dim), return_sequences=True)) # The batch dimension is implicit here
model.add(LSTM(note_dim))
# ...
```

---

**UPDATE:** Answer to your first comment.

`x` should contain all the songs after sliding a window on them. For example, let's suppose you have a variable `songs` with shape `(n_songs, notes_per_song, note_dim)` containing all your songs. Then, you could create `x` and `y` as follows:

```
# ...
# Input data    
# Suppose that variable ´songs´ is an array with shape: (n_songs, notes_per_song, note_dim). 
samples_per_song = notes_per_song-window_length
n_samples = n_songs*samples_per_song
x = np.zeros(shape=(n_samples, window_length, note_dim))
y = np.zeros(shape=(n_samples, note_dim))
for n, song in enumerate(songs):
    for i in range(samples_per_song):
        x[i+n*samples_per_song, :, :] = song[i:(i+window_length), :]
        y[i+n*samples_per_song, :, :] = song[i+window_length, :] # note that you want to predict
# ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. So if I understand well, all the songs should be in the same file? So the file will have NB_songs * 5000 lines? Or maybe x represents one song and i use it as the input and when the NN has done to work with it, I replace x by another song? And what should I add in the output data? I mean how do I build the output?

Comment: How your songs are stored on disk is not very relevant here (there are multiple ways to store and load them). I updated my answer to explain how I would build both the input data `x` and the output `y`. I haven't tested the code that I added, but I hope you get the idea from it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your updated answer! So if I have 2 songs and both have 5000 notes, the array "songs" has  then a shape (2,5000,4) ? And what should be the shape of the new array x and y according to you? (I don't get the values of your variables samples_per_song, n_samples etc...). This new array x will be the input data for the NN.

Comment: Exactly, if you have 2 songs with 5000 notes each, then `songs` has shape `(2, 5000, 4)`. In this case, the shape of `x` would be `(2*(5000-10), 10, 4)` and `y` would be `(2*(5000-10), 4)`. Here, `samples_per_song` holds the number of training examples that you obtain by sliding a window of length `window_length`. For example, note that you can slide 5000-10=4990 times a window of length 10 on a song of length 5000, and each of these vectors is a training example. The label is then the note that comes right after the window. `n_samples` is the total number of examples, combining all the songs.

Comment: Okay I see. Thank you so much. What  you suggested works!! You helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

> I want the NN read the notes with a sequence of 10 notes so that it can predict the next note from them.

I have never used keras but I think you should convert those notes into ids first. For instance: (aa, bb, cc, dd) as 1 and (ab, bb, cc, dd) as 2 and etc.

Then you read 10 ids/notes for the encoder and then add a projection to project the final state to the 11th note. And if you want to test the model with 10 notes from any note in the song you then train the second to the 11th and put the 12th as the target after the projection. And so on and so forth until the last note being as the target. This is for one song and repeat this for all songs.

You can absolutely get the notes back via the ids. You can build a vocabulary to transfer it forth and back.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try to do that. So imagine x, an array with notes for one song. I will then use it as my input data. But how should I build my output data? Should it be same as x without the first 10 notes?

Comment: It depents on your task. In your question you meant to only generate the next one note given the previous ten notes, then I suggest the method in my answer. Could you elaborate your question?

Comment: Yes I want the NN predicts one note from 10 notes. But I need to define an array for the input and the output before doing the machine learning. I know now what to put in input but how should I fill the output? During the first step, the NN will take the 10 first notes and it will do a prediction of the 11th and compare it with the real 11th notes which should be found in the first line of the output. But what about the next part of the output?